# Two dice are rolled and the sum of the face values is less than six. What is the probability that at least one of the dice came up a three?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two dice are rolled and the sum of the face values is less than six. What is the probability that at least one of the dice came up a three?

This is just taking the initial question that I asked and expanding on it: [Two dice are rolled and the sum of the face values is six. What is the probability that at least one of the dice came up a three?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821267/two-dice-are-rolled-and-the-sum-of-the-face-values-is-six-what-is-the-probabili)

**Attempt:**  So since they are requesting that the sum be less than 6 but still have at least one 3 included I felt that the expression should be: $$P(at\ least\ 3| sum < 6) = P(at\ least\ 3| sum = 5) + P(at \ least\ 3| sum = 4)$$ The reason I only have 4,5 is because if we have two dice the only summations that can have a 3 are 4 and 5. This being the case I proceeded: $$P(sum\ of\ 5)= P(5|(3,2))P(3,2) + P(5|(4,1))P(4,1)$$ $$=(1)(\frac{2}{36}) + (1)(\frac{2}{36})$$ Therefore: $$P(at\ least\ 3| sum = 5) = \frac{P(5|(3,2))P(3,2)}{ P(5|(3,2))P(3,2) + P(5|(4,1))P(4,1)}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}$$ $$P(sum\ of\ 4)= P(4|(2,2))P(2,2) + P(4|(3,1))P(3,1)$$ $$=(1)(\frac{1}{36}) + (1)(\frac{2}{36})$$ Therefore: $$=\frac{P(4|(3,1))P(3,1)}{P(4|(2,2))P(2,2) + P(4|(3,1))P(3,1)}$$ 
$$ = (1)(\frac{1}{36} + (1)(\frac{2}{36}$$
$$ = \frac{3}{36}$$

And then I was going to sum up these two according to: $$P(at\ least\ 3| sum < 6) = P(at\ least\ 3| sum = 5) + P(at \ least\ 3| sum = 4)$$

But this then means: $$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3}$$

Which of course is greater than 1.  So where did I go wrong?

Comment: You have 10 outcomes giving a sum less than 6. Out of these, 4 are realized with a dice equal to three... So the correct probability is 0.4

Comment: You seem to have learnt nothing from the correct solution to the earlier problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of decomposing into the various possible sums smaller than 6 is correct, but you need to ponderate them with the probability of the smaller sum itself occuring, i.e.:

$$P(\text{at least }3\mid\text{sum}<6)=\sum_i P(\text{at least }3\mid\text{sum}=i)\times P(\text{sum}=i\mid\text{sum}<6)$$

As you correctly pointed out, the only two possible cases are $i=4,5$. There are $10$ possible cases with a sum smaller than $6$, and we get:
$$P(\text{sum}=5\mid\text{sum}<6)=\dfrac{4}{10}\qquad\text{and}\qquad P(\text{sum}=4\mid\text{sum}<6)=\dfrac{3}{10}$$

Now counting the cases where at least one $3$ occurs:
$$P(\text{at least }3\mid\text{sum}=5)=\dfrac{1}{2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad P(\text{at least }3\mid\text{sum}=4)=\dfrac{2}{3}$$

Finally:
$$P(\text{at least }3\mid\text{sum}<6)=\dfrac{1}{2}\times\dfrac{4}{10}+\dfrac{2}{3}\times\dfrac{3}{10}=\dfrac{2}{5}.$$

(Note that, of course, this corresponds to counting the outcomes with at least one $3$ - there are $4$ of them - out of the $10$ possible cases with a sum smaller than $6$).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I see where I went wrong. I haven't encountered a question that needed a treatment where $P(at\ least\ 3| sum = i)\ x\ P(sum = i\ | sum < 6$ I find that the challenge in this problem is really decomposing what is the composite event. Then I could use the techinques that have been learned.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is this:
$$P(at\ least\ 3| sum < 6) = P(at\ least\ 3| sum = 5) + P(at \ least\ 3| sum = 4)$$
which should read: 
$$
\begin{align}
P(at\ least\ 3| sum < 6) = & P(at\ least\ 3| sum = 5)P(sum=5| sum < 6) \\
& + P(at \ least\ 3| sum = 4)P(sum=4| sum < 6)
\end{align}$$

---

---

Added further explanation:

These additional conditional probability multipliers express the part of the whole result space that you're considering at that moment, to weight the "has a $3$" probability accordingly. The full sum should look like:
$$
\begin{align}
P(at\ least\ 3| sum < 6) = & P(at\ least\ 3| sum = 5)P(sum=5| sum < 6) \\
& + P(at \ least\ 3| sum = 4)P(sum=4| sum < 6) \\
& + P(at \ least\ 3| sum = 3)P(sum=3| sum < 6) \\
& + P(at \ least\ 3| sum = 2)P(sum=2| sum < 6) \\
= & P(at\ least\ 3| sum = 5)\times 0.4 \\
& + P(at \ least\ 3| sum = 4)\times 0.3 \\
& + P(at \ least\ 3| sum = 3)\times 0.2\\
& + P(at \ least\ 3| sum = 2)\times 0.1 \\
\end{align}$$

The reason you're quietly ignoring the "$sum=3$" and "$sum=2$" spaces is because you already know that "$at\ least\ 3$" probability in that space is $0$. But they still exist as part of the "$sum<6$" space.

Comment: why multiply by $P(sum = 5|sum < 6)$? If I know which sets of dice add up to less than 6.

Comment: you're doing that to express the part of the possible result space you're thinking about at that moment, to weight the "has a $3$" probability accordingly. The reason you're ignoring the "$sum=3$" and "$sum=2$" spaces is because you already know that "$at\ least\ 3$"probability in that space is $0$. But they still exist as part of the "$sum<6$" space.

Answer (score 1):

Probability for some $3$ when the sum is $5$, probability for some $3$ when the sum is $4$. I call the random variables $X,Y$ for the value of each dice, and $S$ for the value of the sum of both. Then

$$\Pr[X=3\cup Y=3|S<6]=\Pr[X=3\cup Y=3|S=4]\Pr[S=4|S<6]+\Pr[X=3\cup Y=3|S=5]\Pr[S=5|S<6]$$

If $S$ is less than $4$ each probability is zero. We have that

$$\Pr[X=3\cup Y=3|S=4]=\frac23$$

because for $S=4$ we have the throws $(3,1)$, $(1,3)$ and $(2,2)$. And by similar reasons

$$\Pr[X=3\cup Y=3|S=5]=\frac12$$

and

$$\Pr[S=4|S<6]=\frac3{10}\quad \Pr[S=5|S<6]=\frac4{10}$$

Answer (score 0):

Less formal than the other answers, but given the small number sizes involved, you can list out the possibilities and count the ones that meet your criteria.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
&  \text{Die 1} & \text{Die 2} \\ \hline
& 1 & 1 \\ \hline
& 1 & 2 \\ \hline
\sqrt{} & 1 & 3 \\ \hline
& 1 & 4 \\ \hline
& 2 & 1 \\ \hline
& 2 & 2 \\ \hline
\sqrt{} & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\sqrt{} & 3 & 1 \\ \hline
\sqrt{} & 3 & 2 \\ \hline
& 4 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$